# One liner for login using su

Tags: command-line, bash, login, password

I know you can use `su` to switch users within the terminal. As the account I use is non-root (without superuser permissions), it brings up a password prompt for the user I log into.

Is there a way to use `su` or something similar to login using a one line command? For example,

```
su -l USERNAME PASSWORD
```

Something like this could be used in a bash script for example.

Comment: Use expect, it is not a good idea to include passwords in text files. https://www.lifewire.com/linus-unix-command-expect-2201096

Comment: @bodhi.zazen Ah, could you give me an example for this scenario?

Comment: Well IMO use sudo `sudo -u USERNAME COMMAND`, it will use your password or you can configure sudo to run your command without a password. I can not give you a better example unless you post your script and describe what you are doing and why, probably a better way, but hard to tell.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen Unfortunately using a non-sudo account as well. The script doesn't run any commands once logged in. Just a method to log in without typing a password.

Comment: The advantage of sudo is that you can configure it to allow access only those commands you wish. Again, if you need help, post additional details.

Comment: I agree with @Panther, that this is what `sudo` is for. If that is not an option, you may use `ssh USERNAME@localhost` with key-based authentication as workaround if an ssh-server is installed. Otherwise, an `expect` script could do.

Answer (score 1):

While I wouldn't recommend it (unless the use case explicitly calls for it), you can use something like the following in a shell script:

```
"echo PASSWORD | sudo -S COMMAND"
```

Where PASSWORD is the user password, and COMMAND is the command to run at the elevated permissions level.

Note that the `-S` option is important, as it redirects input from term to standard input. See [Sudo Manual](https://www.sudo.ws/man/1.8.3/sudo.man.html) for additional details.

Comment: Is there a non-sudo alternative?

Comment: From your follow-on question, I'm a bit more unclear on your use case. Perhaps you can provide a good use case for your issue.

That said, to answer your question: not at a command level, though you could always alter user permissions held in `/etc/pam.d/su`. For details on that solution over on [User & Linux SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/113754/allow-user1-to-su-user2-without-password). 

But again, I'd use caution until we have a more specific idea of what it is that you want to do.